# unable to click on a button in selenium in android device manager site

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I can't click on the ring button on an android device manager website. How I can do this? I can easily click on buttons on other sites but in this site I can't.

The HTML code is this:

```
<button class="nova-button ring-dialog-open" title="Ring this device"><div class="ring-device"></div><div class="ring-text">Ring</div></button>
```

and my java code is:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("device-button-column device-button-ring")).click();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compound classes are not supported by selenium. Instead change it to cssSelector shown as follows:

```
button.nova-button.ring-dialog-open
```

*Implementation:*

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.nova-button.ring-dialog-open")).click();
```